# How to keep Wake On WirelessLan enabled after shutdown / reboot

Tags: wireless, 18.04, power-management, 18.10, wakeonlan

My Latitude E7240 running Ubuntu 18.10 has *Wireless* Wake On Lan capability and the option is enabled in the BIOS.

While the Wake On Lan is working like a charm with ethtool, the Wireless variant gives me problems.

With `iw dev` the wireless shows up as phy0.

If I enable the WoWLan with `sudo iw phy0 wowlan enable magic-packet` 
and check it with `iw phy0 wowlan show` it states: 'WoWLAN is enabled'.

However, after rebooting my PC and checking `iw phy0 wowlan show` it states: 'WoWLAN is disabled'.

So my question is: How to keep the WoWLAN enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file: /etc/rc.local

```
#!/bin/sh
iw phy0 wowlan enable magic-packet
exit 0
```

Save the file and make it executable with this command:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

Reboot and test WoWLAN

Comment: Thanks, the WoWLAN works now after reboot.

The PC wakes up while in Sleep, Suspend and hibernate when the magic package is sent.

Still the PC doesn't start when turned off.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
NETDOWN=no
```

to `/etc/default/halt`. See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/halt.5.html

Comment: That worked in Ubuntu Trusty (14.04), but in 18.04 that man page is no longer there.